# Avoiding repeating long paths in image tags

Tags: jekyll, kramdown

I'm using Jekll and kramdown to build a static side.

I am often repeating the same large paths to things in assets in image tags, like:

```
![Some image title](/assets/foo/bar/2019-03-17/more/stuff/groundbreaking-plot.svg)
```

Can I somehow save the `/assets/foo/bar/2019-03-17/more/stuff` portion in a per-page variable so I can refer to it succintly in the markdown, like:

```
![Some image title](??assets_for_this_entry??/groundbreaking-plot.svg)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can set it in the [front matter](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/front-matter/). You can set [custom variables](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/front-matter/#custom-variables) for each page.

```
---
... other stuff in front matter
myPath: /assets/foo/bar/2019-03-17/more/stuff
---

![]({{ page.myPath }}/image.svg }}}
```